# Leaflet Map Is Not Rendering In My React CodeSandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I am trying to get a codesandbox to work in the same way as a reference codesandbox. The original is here...

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-map-with-marker-forked-qd91w

It renders a lovely map in the middle of the browser.

But with my own (which has a clone of the component and almost the same dependencies)

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-ihh5t

It's coming up completely scattered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the leaflet css file. Add https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css to the `External resources` section under the `Dependencies` section on the left hand side.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-forked-sr3di

Comment: Hi Dennis. Thank you so much for the quick answer!